# Vue.js show file name event.target.files

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making an upload functionality in my webapp with vue 2. Currently it looks like this:

```
<label class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" @change="onFileChange" multiple/>
    Upload file
</label>

input[type="file"]  {
  display: none;
}


onFileChange() {
    this.reaction.attachment = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
}
```

So now I would like to show the file names that are on the `event.target.files` object.

I've tried this:

```
<p v-for="file in reaction.attachment">
  {{ file.name }}
</p>
```

But that's not working!? When I look into my vue devtools the attachment object looks like this:

```
attachment:FileList
```

So how do I get this to work?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Whats your Vue code?

Answer (score 11):

You need to get file name using `document.getElementById("fileId").files[0].name` inside onFileChange function.

```
<label class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="fileId" @change="onFileChange" multiple/>
    Upload file
</label>
{{fileName}}


input[type="file"]  {
  height:0;
  weight:0;
  //OR
  display:none
}
```

Inside script, pass event to the function.

```
onFileChange(event){
   var fileData =  event.target.files[0];
   this.fileName=fileData.name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a working example in the sandbox you can check it out.
It will work either select one file or multiple
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-wildflower-jljxn?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0):

Following code works when selecting 1 file at a time.
HTML code to show input field and a label using bootstrap classes:

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="idEditUploadVideo"
       v-on:change="videoChoosen">
<label class="custom-file-label" id="idFileName" for="idEditUploadVideo">
    [[videoFileName]]</label>
```

JS code to show file name in the label as soon as user selects a file:

```
var vueVar = new Vue({
    el: '#idSomething',
    data: {
        videoFileName:''
    },
    methods: {
        videoChoosen(event){
            this.videoFileName = event.target.files[0].name;
        }
    },
    delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
});
```